# How to detect nested lists in XML using an XPath expression in PowerShell?

Tags: xml, powershell, odt

We use a PowerShell script and an XSLT stylesheet to publish our release notes in HTML and ODT format on our customer website. But any nested lists in the release notes don't render in the ODT file. We'll tell our tech writers not to create release notes with nested lists anymore but in case they do, we want our script to stop and return an error if it detects any nested lists.

How do I write an XPath expression (to add to our existing PowerShell script) that

1. **stops** the publishing script *and*
2. returns an error if it **detects any nested lists** (in the raw xml of the release notes)?

For example, this release note xml below has a bulleted list () nested within a numbered list (). I want to add something to our PowerShell script to detect this, and all other nested-list scenarios (OL within OL, UL within UL, OL within UL).

```
<shortDescription>Pricing Platform</shortDescription>
<note><P>We've added these new features:</P>
<P>
 <OL>
  <LI>A new Summary Report.</LI>
  <LI>Price Scheme page: We've added a mandatory priority setting to the Price Scheme page.</LI>
  <LI>A new Management page, where you can edit each screen's type.</LI>
  <LI>The following search criteria have been added to the Pricing page:
   <UL>
    <LI>name</LI>
    <LI>cinema</LI>
    <LI>status</LI>
   </UL>
  </LI>
</OL>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# Sample document.
$xmlDoc = [xml] @'
<xml>
<shortDescription>Pricing Platform</shortDescription>
<note><P>We've added these new features:</P>
<P>
 <OL>
  <LI>A new Summary Report.</LI>
  <LI>Price Scheme page: We've added a mandatory priority setting to the Price Scheme page.</LI>
  <LI>A new Management page, where you can edit each screen's type.</LI>
  <LI>The following search criteria have been added to the Pricing page:
   <UL>
    <LI>name</LI>
    <LI>cinema</LI>
    <LI>status</LI>
   </UL>
  </LI>
</OL>
</P>
</note>
</xml>
'@

#'# Execute an XPath query that looks for nested lists of either type
# in any combination, anywhere in the document hierarchy.
# If it returns at least one node, $hasNestedLists will contain $true.
$hasNestedLists = [bool] (Select-Xml -Xml $xmlDoc -XPath '//LI//LI')

if ($hasNestedLists) { Throw "Nested lists found." }
```

<sup>Tip of the hat to [Michael Kay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/415448/michael-kay) for providing the much simpler `//LI//LI` XPath query, which simply looks for nested list *items*, which automatically covers both `<OL>` and `<UL>` lists; the original query was:
`//OL//UL | //UL//OL | //OL//OL | //UL//UL`</sup>